# Freepbx can't connect to asterisk wrong password

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx

I've just setup FreePBX on my VPS. Everything is OK there are no notices. There hasn't been any errors in the installation. When I create my extension from the FreePBX create new SIP extension and try to connect afterwards I get Forbidden on my SIP client. The extension and the password are the same as I setup in the PBX. 
This is the message from the log:

[2014-11-25 23:53:49] NOTICE[9209] chan_sip.c: Registration from '<sip:777@$$SERVER_IP$$>' failed for '$$MY_IP$$:59096' - Wrong password

The strange thing is that when I create an extension from the sip_custom.conf I connect to the server successfuly. 
Any ideas :?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have do apply changes(red button) after each change

You also have ensure your nat settings setuped correctly

You can check that device added in sip_additional.conf file and in asterisk via

```
asterisk -rx "sip show users"
```

Again, if you use nat=no and your device after nat, it will not work. Same can be if you use nat=yes and you have no nat.